# C# is it possible to explicitly resolve a collision between 2 types with the same full name?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have a project which references 2 assemblies, A and B.

Both A and B declare a public type with the same full name (e. g. Foo.Bar).

When I build, it seems like the compiler picks one type to reference and then throws a warning. Is there some way I can be explicit about which implementation I want to use (e. g. Foo.Bar from assembly A)?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `extern alias`. You have to compile your code with a /r switch for each dll.

`csc /r:AssemblyA=A.dll /r:AssemblyB=B.dll [myProject]`

Or you can set the assembly's alias by selecting it in your project's `References` folder and set its `Aliases` property using the `properties window`.

Then in your `.cs` file use `extern alias` to explicitly choose which type you want to use:

```
extern alias AssemblyA;
extern alias AssemblyB;

public class Test
{
   public void TestMethod()
   {
      var aFooBar = new AssemblyA.Foo.Bar();
      var bFooBar = new AssemblyB.Foo.Bar(); 
   }
}
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx).

Comment: This looks promising! Is there a way to specify those flags when building from visual studio (somewhere in properties, maybe?)

Comment: You can set the alias in properties window when you select the referenced dll in solution explorer.

Answer (score -1):

You can Reference Full Method Name including Assembly,

like A.Foo.Bar Or B.Foo.Bar

Hope this help you...

Answer (score -2):

Are you already referring to the FooBar class like this: A.FooBar or B.FooBar ?

Because if you want to use two assemblies at the same time, you can either specify explicitly which one you want to use to call the FooBar from like I've mentioned.

If you also don't want to use the full name in case it's too long you can create an alias in your using statement

[How to use alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)

Comment: `A` and `B` are the assembly names, but they are not part of the fully-qualified type name.  See brz's answer.

Comment: I didn't find the question very clear is why I asked, secondly to the way the question was asked is how to use the same class name from two different assemblies

Comment: Plus I written my answer first before anyone has written anything meanie :)